# IOS development: Strange effect during flip horizontal modal

Tags: iphone

I've encountered a strange situation that during the flip transition(UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal) between views the iphone desktop appeared as the background. I can even see app and icons on my iphone when the view is flipping into another.

Is it due to the improper management of memory or not correctly customized settings?

Comment: Sounds like you've forgotten to call some `[super viewWillAppear:animated]` or similar. But maybe you can share you're code ;)